# Required attribute 'select' is missing

Tags: xslt

So I have the following code:

```html
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="/MxML/packages/package/packageId">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(/MxML/packages/package/packageId/internalId, '.0')"/>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="/MxML/trades/trade[$idx_ope]/tradeHeader/contractReference[@mefClass='mxContractStbICONTRACT']">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(/MxML/contracts/contract/contractId/internalId, '.0')"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(0, '.0')"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

and recieve the error: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: line 1: Required attribute 'select' is missing.

But i can see all the 'select' this code need. What else could be the problem?

Comment: I am not sure if there is anything wrong with that block of code. It probably help if you showed a complete sample of XSLT that has the error, just in case the issue lies elsewhere. Thank you

Comment: One doubt while creating the `$idx_ope` is it param or variable. See this or post more XSLT code.